# Whats a good practice to new implementation in same XML?

Tags: c#, web-services, web, asp.net-web-api, soap

I have a web service that I want to implement new features. I wonder if it's a good practice to add them to the default XML or should I create new methods for this consumption?

An example: I have a method that returns the characteristics of a product, color, price, size, etc. I want to implement a new feature that will also return the price on several websites. Actual XML:

```
<Product>
    <Name> IPhone X </Name>
    <Color> Black </Color>
    <Type> Smartphone </Type>
</Product>
```

New XML:

```
<Product>
    <Name> IPhone X </Name>
    <Color> Black </Color>
    <PriceInSites>
        <Site> www.apple.com </Site>
        <Price> 1000.00 </Price>
    <PriceInSites>
    <Type> Smartphone </Type>
</Product>
```

Whereas multiple clients already use the implementation without this XML block - should I make this available in a separate method?

Whats a good practice to new implementation in same XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your new XML, your closing PriceInSites tag should look like this `</PriceInSites>` instead of this `<PriceInSites>`. Second, the answer depends on how much work your clients are willing to do to consume the new XML. I don't see your XML schema documents, so assuming your original schema looked something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Type">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=" Smartphone "/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Name"/>
                <xs:element ref="Color"/>
                <xs:element ref="Type"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Name">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=" IPhone X "/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Color">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=" Black "/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then your new XML schema should make the newly inserted tag optional:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Type">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=" Smartphone "/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Site">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=" www.apple.com "/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Name"/>
                <xs:element ref="Color"/>
                <xs:element ref="PriceInSites" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="Type"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="PriceInSites">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Site"/>
                <xs:element ref="Price"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Price">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                <xs:enumeration value="1000.0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Name">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=" IPhone X "/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Color">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=" Black "/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

...by setting minOccurs to zero. You should only do this if you wish to continue to support your existing XML schema consumers that are unwilling or unable to update their XML definition to handle your new element.